Expectation operator for a joint distribution
This video shows that for a joint probability distribution $X,Y$:
$$E[aX+bY+c]=aE[X]+bE[Y]+c$$
While the video does it using the definition of the expectation of a joint distribution (and which I understand), would it wrong to simply apply linearity of expectation and say
$$E[aX+bY+c]=E[aX]+E[bY]+E[c]=aE[X]+bE[Y]+c$$
Note: If what I have done is wrong, I am interested in what is wrong. (The video already mentions one approach, quite possibly there are others).

In your second equation, I see $x$ where it should read $X$, and also there's an uppercase $C$ on the left that becomes $c$ on the right. Can you edit to use symbols consistently?

But there's a more substantial error. A constant random variable $c$ has probability mass function entirely concentrated at $c$, so its expectation is also $c$, but $E[c]c = E[c^2]$, which is not what you want. If you want to express your linear combination in terms of a basis, you need the constant "random variable" $1$, so the basis is ${X, Y, 1}$. Then
$$
E[aX + bY + c] = aE[x] + bE[y] + cE[1].
$$

Yes, expectation is linear. However, how do you know that expectation is linear? If you define expectation as Lebesgue integral, then it's OK. But in different contexts, like the one you are in, (where I am assuming you are not using the Lebesgue integral to define expectation), your reasoning is circular.

@Andrew So then the video $proves$ that expectation is linear, while I am using the property. Hence, the video builds it up from the foundation, and I cannot use it without proving it. Is my understanding correct? (Note that the context of the video is discrete joint random variables, and I would like to assume I am working in the same context).

Yes, your understanding is correct.
